# Show success message of upload action HTML, NodeJS

Tags: html, node.js, response, multer

I upload a file in HTML with nodejs module MULTER:

```
<form enctype   =  "multipart/form-data"
      action    =  "/upload"
      method    =  "POST">

<input type="file" name="file" >
<p></p>
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">

</form>

  <span>{{submit.message}}</span>
```

I want to show the response message not in on a new page which is now, I want to show it in the message span.

```
var upload = multer({ storage : storage}).single('file');

    router.post('/upload', function(req, res){
        upload(req, res, function(err) {
            if(err){
                return res.status(400).send({
                    message: 'wrong'
                });
                console.log("Error: '" + err + "'");
            }else{
                return res.status(200).send({
                    message: 'fine'
                });
           console.log('Uploaded file: ' + req.file.filename);
            }
        });
    });
```

angularjs:

```
this.submit = function() {
        $http.post("/upload", data)
        .then(
                function(res) {
                    console.log("posted successfully");
                    this.message = "succesful";
                },
                function(res) {
                    console.log(res.data.message);
                   this.message = res.data.message
                }
            );
      }
```

How can I parse the response message to the html file without opening a new page. I want to show the response message in the html span response.
Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Please learn about HTTP protocols and why a POST request needs a page load. This will lead you down the track of how you can submit a POST request with AJAX. So far you haven't done enough work to warrant an answer.

Comment: @Tom I don't want to submit the post request with ajax. I want to get the message if the file is uploaded or an error occured!

Comment: So if you don't submit a POST request with Ajax and you don't want a page load, how do you propose the data gets sent to the server?

Comment: It works fine only with the nodejs module multer, without ajax. The file upload is working, I just want the success logged in the console, be send to the span tag in the html page.